# php oop, classes in multiple files

Tags: php, oop, class

I am coding "simple" filemanager for my customer.
Registered users can upload files and view previously uploaded files and administrator can manipulate uploaded respectively. Files are stored in filesystem but other information is stored in MySQL.

I have done main db settings class (db_settings) which has properties like database username and password etc.

Second class is for user authentication and this class extends db_settings class. 
This class has one property, user object (properties: username, language, etc).

A new user object is created in second class after user is logged in.

User interface is one page which load and include needed subpages by url parameter.

Subpage is combined with html/php-page and classfile according to current page.

When user is uploading file and he clicks "Upload file", upload page (page_upload.php) is included in main page and upload class is then included in that same page (include_once 'class_upload.php').

Second class is extended on class_upload.php so the top level methods are accessible on every subclass.

Problem is that the user object is not populated when user is on subpage (ie. upload page) and therefore those properties are not available.

How user object properties can be accessed also from subpages?

I want to keep classes in separate files and dont want to use autoloader.

Comment: Have you considered using sessions? http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Answer (score 1):

sounds like you need a simple framework like codeigniter or kohana.
if you don't want this, create kind of registry where everything you definitely need is loaded. Then include this registry class in every file you work with. And the autoloader is not that bad...

Answer (score 0):

Without any real code, this is a bit hard to get through.

However, I can give you this advice. The way you are extending your classes is a bad practice. Don't extend classes because it's 'convenient' to have certain methods in your current class.

On your main 'bootstrap' or 'index' page, just include a couple of class-files and instantiate a couple of objects.

Your "UploadPage" class can receive the DbSettings and Auhtentication classes in a constructor.

Hope you don't take this badly, but it would likely also a good idea for you to use a framework first and see how they do things. It may give you some inspiration for better design.

The 'I don't want to use an autoloader' requirement seems weird to me, but fortunately you can just include classes manually, easily.

Answer (score 0):

At first few notes:

> Second class is for user authentication and this class extends
>   db_settings class. This class has one property, user object
>   (properties: username, language, etc).

Why does this class extend `db_settings`, shouldn't it just **use** it?

> User interface is one page which load and include needed subpages by url parameter.

I just hope you're validating page parameter (against wrong input such as: `http://my.code.com/file.txt`, `../index` (recursive inclusion of itself), ...).

#### Answer to the question:

You probably need to store object in [`$_SESSION`](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php) (either [serialized](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) or plain, based on what you need... It will be serialized anyway when storing to file so you may need to take a look on [`__sleep()` and `__wakeup()` methods](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.sleep)).

Don't forget to `include 'class_user.php'` before calling to [`session_start()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) so object can be initialized properly.